What exactly is intensity of magnetization and magnetic field intensity?
What is intensity of magnetization (I) and magnetic field intensity (H)? What is the difference between them?
I saw some similar questions but I either didn't understand the answers or I understood only a part of it... I read in one answer that (I) is the number of magnetic dipole per volume... So does that mean that in the formula H, B/§ ( I don't know how to put "mew nought" in the formula) is also the number of magnetic dipoles per volume?

Where did you see this information, I have not seen anyone refer to intensity of magnetization as a property, much less with the letter $I$ which might be confused with current in some circles.
